# How to analyze a dataframe with multiple headers?

Tags: python, pandas, header, multiple-columns, multi-index

For example, I have a df with 3 headers. I want to analyze data from one of the columns in the first header and one of the columns in the second header. How do i do that?
[image: Example of df]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know if this will work because you haven't provided you're data but you can try this.

First access the column names

```
data.columns
```

Then isolate the corresponding columns you would like to analyze

```
data = data[['column_1', 'column_2']]
```

Index the columns based on the names that appear as the current column names, ignore the column names not currently used and just index based on the corresponding match.

You can then rename the columns.

```
data.columns = ['new_column_1_name', 'new_column_2_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull them out as tuples:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=[["A", "B"], ["a", "b"]])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [13]: df[[("A", "a")]]
Out[13]:
   A
   a
0  1
1  3
```

In your case it might be:

```
df[[("Year", "All ages")]]
```

*See the [advanced section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) for multi-index indexing and slicing.*